# could not execute "manage.py"command in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, django-models, pycharm

I have a DJANGO project and I want to migrate changes in models.py with "manage.py makemigrations" but when use that in Pycharm's terminal , manage.py files open and show this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project2ofC4.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

[image]

how can I active virtual environment?

Comment: Go through this documentation, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment in the first place ?

Comment: yes ,I use virtual environment in first place.

Comment: Settings -> Project -> Project interpreter. Then add your virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

You have to open `manage.py` console(not manage.py file). To open `manage.py` console press Ctrl+Alt+R(all together).
In the opened console the name will be shown as `manage.py@project_name`
In this console type `makemigrations App_name 0001`
Then, after this type `migrate` and press `Enter` and that's it!. Your migrations has successfully done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to activate your virtual environment :

*Linux :

```
source name_of_your_env/bin/activate
```

*Windows:

```
\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: in windows command" path" is the location of my virtual environment for project??

Comment: No , just figure out where is the location of your virtual env and paste it instead of path\to\env the add \scripts\activate